# Why does adding an image dynamically take so much memory

Tags: html, image

I am adding some images dynamically and I've realised it takes a lot of memory and I can't understand why

I've created a snippet to replicate.

The .svg file I'm adding is about 2mb, but according to task manager in Windows, after I add the image, the memory usage of the browser jumps by at least 40mb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="img" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="click"/>
    <script>
        const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        btn.addEventListener("click", addImage);

        function addImage() {
            const img = document.getElementById("img");
            img.src = "wwwroot/MyProj/Images/myTwoMb.svg";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my case, if the user chooses to, they can load all images this way. On disc, the entire folder is about 80mb of svg files. It takes over 1GB of memory.

I print to PDF and as such, need the images to remain as .svg

When I try this with a .jpg, the issue still occurs

I don't know what I can do to fix this

Comment: I also used https://www.sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-30mb.jpg to test a 30mb file, and it used over 300mb of memory

Comment: SVG are effectively converted to raster images internally for display. Similarly, compressed images (such as jpg) are uncompressed internally for display.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that HTML tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.

Comment: For printing to PDF, A Document Library like LEADTOOLS (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor) can [convert](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-converter) SVG directly to PDF to avoid intensive rendering. The library can also improve the performance of rendering large files through configuring the [MaximumImagePixelSize](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/javascript/dox/loaddocumentoptions-maximumimagepixelsize.html) property which limits the maximum size of the rendered image and scales it appropriately.